# How to Fix Error: "Property 'push' does not exist on type 'NavigateFunction'" in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm encountering an error while trying to use React-Router-DOM in my React application. Specifically, I'm trying to use the push function on a `NavigateFunction`, but TypeScript is throwing the error:

> Property 'push' does not exist on type 'NavigateFunction'

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export function HomeScreen() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate.push({
      pathname: '/Contact',
      state: { text: text }
    });
  };
```

I'm not sure why TypeScript is giving this error, as I believe push should be a valid function on `NavigateFunction`. How can I resolve this error and properly use the push function with `NavigateFunction` in React-Router-DOM?

Comment: Implementation is wrong. Use this -  `navigate('/Contact', { state: { text: text }});`